# i want to pass a variable from one class to another and use it in Label widget using python and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to pass variable `n` from `startpage` to `page1`. Then put the variable into a label widget called `label_country`. How can I do this within `tkinter`? I tried calling the variable by the class and I also used the `n.get()` method.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self, height=1000, width=1000, bg="gray")
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
    
        for F in (StartPage, Page1):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
    
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="gray")
    
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('W.TButton', foreground='black', background='white'
                        )
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="slect a country ", style='W.TButton',
                            command=lambda: [ controller.show_frame(Page1)])
        button.place(relx=0.66, rely=0.05, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.07)
    
        ttk.Label(self, text="country slect:").place(relx=0.14, rely=0.05, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.07)
    
        n = tk.StringVar()
    
        country_choice = ttk.Combobox(self, width=27, textvariable=n)
        country_choice["values"] = ([x for x in df["Country"].unique()])
        country_choice.place(relx=0.14, rely=0.05, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.07)
        country_choice.current()
        text_box = tk.Text(self, height=28, width=30, bg="white")
        text_box.insert(tk.INSERT, "INFORMATIONT ABOUT THE PROGRAM")
        text_box.config(state="disabled")
        text_box.place(relx=0.14, rely=0.15, )

class Page1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="gray")
    
        label_country = tk.Label(self, text= StartPage.n, bg = "white")
        label_country.place(relx=0.795, rely=0.13, relwidth=0.0755, relheight=0.03)

app = tkinterApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: FYI, "*I'll be real with you. I'm typing out more then I need to, in order to get that little ! symbol thing off the side of the screen so I can post this question.*" is against the site policy.

Comment: Do any of the links in this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/7432